# Dismiss iPad Keyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, keyboard

I am creating an iOS application for iPhone and iPad and some of my screens have UITextFields. I want the keyboard to be dismissed when the user clicks off of the text box. To do this I have wrote the following code:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
     [firstName resignFirstResponder];
     [lastName resignFirstResponder];
     [email resignFirstResponder];
     [password resignFirstResponder];
     [retypePassword resignFirstResponder];
}
```

This works fine for the iPhone, but it doesn't work for the keyboard on iPad. I have searched on the net and all the sugeestions do not work. The main suggestion is:

```
- (BOOL)disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal {
       return NO;
}
```

But this still does not work?
Any help would appreciated.

Comment: How is your controller displayed? If it is presented modally as a form sheet then iOS will sometimes not allow you to dismiss the keyboard as the form sheet moves when this happens. It just makes for a nicer behaviour.

Comment: Did you make sure that the variables are linked to the iPad-views in IB (in case you are using it)?

Comment: @GeorgeGreen - Yes I am presenting it modally using a form sheet. Thanks for the explanation. Is there any way around this? Can't understand why it works on the iPhone but not the iPad

Comment: On the iPhone you can only present fullscreen, whereas on the iPad it shows it in a window that gets positioned higher on the screen when the keyboard presents. To avoid moving it too much, iOS often keeps it up. I have had the same issue before and spent quite a while trying to solve it. The only option I have come up with is to present in another style.

Comment: I'm using the same method.. -(BOOL)disableAutomaticKeyboardDismissal.. in my modal view and is working fine... Try to add [self.view endEditing:YES]; in your touchesBegan method

Answer (score -1):

```
Add this method to .h file, 
-(IBAction)fn_resign:(id)sender;


Inherit your XIB to UIControl and just add following method to the view.

And in file's owner assign this method to view.

in .m:
-(IBAction)fn_resign:(id)sender{
   //Hide you keyboard.
}
```